# Arduino code works when connected to laptop, not when connected to battery or wall socket

Tags: arduino-nano

So I have an Arduino nano, and I am using two SG90 servos, and 1 BMP280, and 1 MPU6050. My code works fine when I plug my nano into my computer, but when I connect the battery to my nano, it doesn't run. The servo moves to 90 degrees, but it seems that it is not detecting the sensor data and not moving the servo. I commented out all calls to `Serial`.
Here is my code:

```
/***************************************************************************
  This is a library for the BMP280 humidity, temperature & pressure sensor

  Designed specifically to work with the Adafruit BMP280 Breakout
  ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/2651

  These sensors use I2C or SPI to communicate, 2 or 4 pins are required
  to interface.

  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit andopen-source hardware by purchasing products
  from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried & Kevin Townsend for Adafruit Industries.
  BSD license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 ***************************************************************************/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP280.h>

// MPU
#include <MPU6050.h>

// Servo 
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servoY;
Servo servoX;

MPU6050 mpu;

// Timers
unsigned long timer = 0;
float timeStep = 0.01;

// Pitch, Roll and Yaw values
float pitch = 0;
float roll = 0;
float yaw = 0;


#define BMP_SCK  (13)
#define BMP_MISO (12)
#define BMP_MOSI (11)
#define BMP_CS   (10)

Adafruit_BMP280 bmp; // I2C
//Adafruit_BMP280 bmp(BMP_CS); // hardware SPI
//Adafruit_BMP280 bmp(BMP_CS, BMP_MOSI, BMP_MISO,  BMP_SCK);

void pitch_roll_yaw(){
  // Serial.print("Pitch: ");
  // Serial.println(pitch);

  // Serial.print("Roll: ");
  // Serial.println(roll);

  // Serial.print("Yaw: ");
  // Serial.println(yaw);
  int thsjsojf = 1;
}


void setup() {
  // Servo
  servoY.attach(8);
  servoY.write(90);

  servoX.attach(9);
  servoX.write(90);


  // Serial.begin(115200);
  // while ( !Serial ) delay(100);   // wait for native usb
  // Serial.println(F("BMP280 test"));
  unsigned status;
  //status = bmp.begin(BMP280_ADDRESS_ALT, BMP280_CHIPID);
  status = bmp.begin();
  if (!status) {
    // Serial.println(F("Could not find a valid BMP280 sensor, check wiring or "
    //                   "try a different address!"));
    // Serial.print("SensorID was: 0x"); Serial.println(bmp.sensorID(),16);
    // Serial.print("        ID of 0xFF probably means a bad address, a BMP 180 or BMP 085\n");
    // Serial.print("   ID of 0x56-0x58 represents a BMP 280,\n");
    // Serial.print("        ID of 0x60 represents a BME 280.\n");
    // Serial.print("        ID of 0x61 represents a BME 680.\n");
    while (1) delay(10);
  }

  /* Default settings from datasheet. */
  bmp.setSampling(Adafruit_BMP280::MODE_NORMAL,     /* Operating Mode. */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X2,     /* Temp. oversampling */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::SAMPLING_X16,    /* Pressure oversampling */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::FILTER_X16,      /* Filtering. */
                  Adafruit_BMP280::STANDBY_MS_500); /* Standby time. */


  // MPU
  while(!mpu.begin(MPU6050_SCALE_2000DPS, MPU6050_RANGE_2G))
  {
    // Serial.println("Could not find a valid MPU6050 sensor, check wiring!");
    delay(500);
  }
  
  // Calibrate gyroscope. The calibration must be at rest.
  // If you don't want calibrate, comment this line.
  mpu.calibrateGyro();

  // Set threshold sensivty. Default 3.
  // If you don't want use threshold, comment this line or set 0.
  mpu.setThreshold(3);

}

int incrementPitch = 0;
int curAngle = 90;
int incrementPitchDown = 0;

void loop() {
    timer = millis();
    // Read normalized values
    Vector norm = mpu.readNormalizeGyro();

    // Calculate Pitch, Roll and Yaw
    pitch = pitch + norm.YAxis * timeStep;
    roll = roll + norm.XAxis * timeStep;
    yaw = yaw + norm.ZAxis * timeStep;

    float normalY = norm.YAxis;


    // Serial.print(F("Temperature = "));
    // Serial.print(bmp.readTemperature());
    // Serial.println(" *C");

    // Serial.print(F("Pressure = "));
    // Serial.print(bmp.readPressure());
    // Serial.println(" Pa");

    // Serial.print(F("Approx altitude = "));
    // Serial.print(bmp.readAltitude(1013.25)); /* Adjusted to local forecast! */
    // Serial.println(" m");

    // pitch_roll_yaw();


    //TODO: This works, but if pitch > 1 and the servo arm is already at max, it doesn't move. Fix. 
    // TODO: If pitch < 1. move the servo in the opposite way by 5 degrees. Need to track current angle.
    if(pitch>1){
      // Serial.println("PITCH IS GREATER++++++THAN 1, MOVING Y SERVO");
      servoY.write(curAngle+incrementPitch);
      curAngle = curAngle+incrementPitch;
      // Serial.print("Pitch: ");Serial.println(pitch);
      if(curAngle>180){
        // This is just so we don't print the current angle if curAngle > 180. This can be antything.
        int something = 1;
      } else {
        // Serial.print("Current Angle of Y servo: ");Serial.println(curAngle);
      }
      incrementPitch+=6;
    } else if(pitch<-1){
      // TODO: If pitch is < -1, then we move the servo in 5 degree increments starting at the current angle. Right now it jumps some degrees, check the if(pitch>1) for errors? MUST FIX.
      // Serial.println("Pitch is LESS---------THAN 1, MOVING Y SERVO");
      servoY.write(curAngle-incrementPitchDown);
      curAngle = curAngle-incrementPitchDown;
      incrementPitchDown+=6;
    }



    // Serial.println();
    delay(200);
}
```

ALso, none of the other threads solve my problems.

Comment: what battery are you using?

Comment: @jsotola a 9v battery

Comment: do you mean a standard 9 V block battery like these? ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=9v+battery&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @jsotola yes precisely

Comment: those are for powering low current devices like smoke alarms ... it is surprising that there is enough current to move the servo even once

Comment: So, what should I use to power it? I am using my Arduino in a model rocket so it can't be too heavy.

Comment: the 9 V battery contains six AAAA cells in series ... try six AA cells for testing ... you may have to choose another battery chemistry for higher power density

Comment: How long should the circuit work? It's not the capacity, but the current that's limiting you. -- You could look for a rechargeable battery like NiMH or LiIon. Make sure you read the data sheet and check that it can deliver enough current. Of course you need to find the required current, by measuring or reading the data sheets of your Arduino and the other parts like the servo.

Answer (score 0):

If are you powering the servo's via your Nano (and thus the USB port), this will cause problems. The Servo's need need 500/700 mA each (>1 Amp total). My laptop USB is 500mA, so rotating two servo's will cause a power drop (voltage goes down due the draw of current).

in my experience using servo's when connected to a computer/laptop is not reliable. This will happen: the servo rotates, the power drops causing the Microcontroller to restart or cause problems (voltage) for the  sensor.

Comment: So how will I power them?

Comment: connect an external 5v supply tot the servo's (PowerBank/USB charger/5V LED driver/anything 5V). Connect this power supply to the GND of Servo's AND the board (important!).

 Connect the board to the laptop via USB (now the board is powered by your laptop and the servo's via an external supply).

Upload code and test